# ¿Como guardar nombres de productos en Base de Datos en variables para luego mostrar en un MessageBox de WindowsForms?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, interfaz-gráfica

Tengo el siguiente código que se ejecuta cuando se hace click en un botón que tiene como leyenda "CERRAR MESA".
Lo que el código hace es borrar toda la info de esa mesa de la base de datos! Hasta ahí anda bien. Lo que necesito ahora es que antes de borrarlos me liste los productos en un MessageBox para que el usuario pueda mandar el ticket a imprimir y luego si, que se cierre la mesa.

Lo que no logro hacer andar es que me devuelva el nombre del producto de la BD en una variable para luego poder mostrarle los datos al usuario.

Acá les dejo el código que tengo:

```
        // CIERRA LA MESA Y ELIMINA TODOS SUS DATOS
    private void btnCerrarMesa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string nombre = "";
        string mesa = this.numMesa.Trim();
        String consulta_productos = "Select nombre from Productos where mesa = @mesa";
        SQLiteCommand comd = new SQLiteCommand(consulta_productos, conexion);
        comd.Parameters.Clear();
        comd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@mesa", mesa));
        using (SQLiteDataReader read = comd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (read.Read())
            {
                // he aqui el problema: necesito que el campo "nombre" de mi base de datos sea guardado en esta variable "nombre" de mi función para luego poder mostrarla más abajo en el MessageBox!
                nombre = consulta_productos;

            }
        }

        // DE ACÁ PARA ABAJO ANDA BIEN

        DialogResult confirmar = MessageBox.Show("¿Cerrar la mesa?", "", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        if (confirmar == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            String consulta = "DELETE FROM Productos where mesa = @mesa";
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(consulta, conexion);

            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@mesa", mesa));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            f1.cambiarFondoDefecto();
            this.Close();
            String info = "";
            String total = "";
            info += "Mesa:" + mesa.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            // en la variable nombre (que debería ser un arreglo o una lista) me gustaría que se guarden los nombres de los productos de ESA mesa para poder mostrarlos.
            MessageBox.Show(info, nombre);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al ejecutar tu consulta

```
using (SQLiteDataReader read = comd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (read.Read())
            {
             nombre = read.GetString(0);    
            }
        }
```

read es un array de resultados, donde puedes tomarlo desde su función [GetString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018114/read-data-from-sqldatareader)

Comment: querido @AaronRomero
Tengo esto, pero no me compila:
        using (SQLiteDataReader read = comd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                    foreach (var i as read)
                    {
                        lista.add(read.GetString(i));
                    }
            }

Comment: no le gusta la condición dentro del foreach y dice que espera un "in", me podrías ayudar ?

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionar? Como es algo distinto, podemos seguir en el chat.

Comment: Usé tu solución para hacer una nueva pregunta de la cual ya obtuve respuesta. Hoy a la tarde lo pruebo y si no anda tendré que buscarte en el chat de nuevo. Gracias por todo hermano :D

Comment: te quería avisar que ya logré hacer lo que necesitaba. Es para un trabajo que tengo que entregar el jueves. Muchisimas gracias por tu tiempo y tu ayuda, solo eso. Te mando un gran abrazo

Comment: excelente hermano. Me alegro por ti. Buenas vibras.